# Can player characters identify monsters?

Tags: monsters, skills, dnd-5e

In D&D 5e, I can't find a skill check for identifying monsters. (Other than Arcana for planar monsters). Can PCs identify monsters, and if so, what skill should they use? (Or is it just a Wis/Int check?)

Comment: Related: [Does D&D 5e have a rule for character knowledge about monsters?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46591), [Does getting information about a monster in combat take an action?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/77580)

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate forward in time because it has that "how do we make old 5e questions up to date" problem, and the forward duplicate is an opportunity to avoid that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's almost certainly *going* to be Wis and Int Checks. The question is which skill proficiencies will apply to those checks depending on what their origin is.

This is generally the Purview of the Monster Manual and DMG, however, Mearls has said that more of Basic D&D is will be released this coming week. We should know a lot more when Basic D&D expands.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing I'm hoping will be in the PHB I guess...

Comment: Took me a while to find a link for the expansion of Basic, I'll add it here in case anyone else goes looking: [escapist](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/news/view/134812-Dungeons-Dragons-Launch-Will-Include-Free-Basic-D-D-Book)

Comment: -1 This answer needs to be updated. I'm surprised it didn't get more support, since players _always_ ask if they "recall" something about any new creature they're confronted with.

Answer (score -3):

As a DM, my rule of thumb is very simple.

If they have encountered the creatures before, then they should be able to identify said monster.  One usually doesn't forget monsters they have encountered.

If they speak the language, they should be able to identify the monster.  Knowledge is power.

If they are part of that race, half-orc / half-elf etc...  they should know what the monster is.

Lastly, if they have dedicated off-adventure time to the study of races and cultures and the monsters race has been in their studies, they would be able to identify the monster.

If not, so sad.  Previous knowledge from other characters played does not allow the characters to have insight.  Common problem.  A dog appears beside you, attacks and shortly thereafter, disappears to reappear a few feet away.  Player yells "Blink Dogs, I know how to kill them"  How did they know it was a blink dog.  The players have to play their current character and the DM has to ensure that they do.  Makes the game a whole lot more fun.

Comment: Wouldn't "dedicated off-adventure time to the study of races and cultures and the monsters race has been in their studies" *be* represented by some sort of check, thus entirely begging the question?

Comment: Hi! Keep in mind that this site is for Q&A and isn't a discussion forum. It feels like this post is a discussion tangent, since it doesn't attempt to address the core question of which skill is used to identify monsters. Maybe you consider that to already be implied by your post, but if so it needs an [edit] to make its core answer to the question **explicit** instead. Thanks! For more about how the site is different from a discussion forum, check out our [tour].